# System of "linear" equations (with XOR operation in $\mathbb{Z}/(2^n)\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[EDITED] (Changed the question)

Hello, now I'm making tables to review it, but it's slow... Xor with product in Z/(2^n) are a ring?

I have a "linear" system like this (we know $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$, we want to know $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$):

$
\begin{array}{ccccccccl}
a\cdot x_1 & \oplus & b\cdot x_2 & \oplus & 0 & \oplus & 0 & = e \\
0 & \oplus & 0 & \oplus & a\cdot x_3 & \oplus & b\cdot x_4 & = f \\
c\cdot x_1 & \oplus & d\cdot x_2 & \oplus & 0 & \oplus & 0 & = g \\
0 & \oplus & 0 & \oplus & c\cdot x_3 & \oplus & d\cdot x_4 & = h \\
\end{array}
$

We can transform the system to two independent equations system, but even if we are working only with 2 unknowns I can't find the way to work with XOR and the typical addition together.

Thanks in advance for any idea :) .

Comment: XOR does not distribute over the regular sum of $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$: for example, with $n=3$, $3$XOR$(1+1) = 3$XOR$2 = 1$, but $3$XOR$1 + 3$XOR$1 = 2+2=4$. Nor does the sum distribute over XOR: $1+(3$XOR$1) = 1+2 = 3$, but $(1+3)$XOR$(1+1) = 4$XOR$2 = 6$.

Comment: Sorry, in any case,¿there's a way to prove that this system is (not) resoluble ?

Comment: @castarco: En ingles, se dicen "unknowns" (=incognitas). Y no se usan los signos de interrogacion o admiracion izquierdos.

Comment: @Arturo gracias, thanks.

Comment: @castarco: Is $\oplus$ meant to be XOR?

Comment: @Arturo: yes :p (it's commonly used by informatic engineers)

Comment: @castarco: No, that's fine. It's just that I didn't notice until later that you had switched from $(Z_{2^n},+,XOR)$ to $(Z_{2^n},XOR,\cdot)$.